# IIS: browser redirect from http://www to https://

Tags: http, redirect, iis, https, dns

I have developed a website in aspnet and it is hosted on a Windows Server 2012 server through IIS 8. We would like to make the site available for the following addresses:

1. https://example.com
2. https://www.example.com
3. http://example.com
4. http://www.example.com

Addresses 1, 2 and 3 work correctly while address 4 do not.

Our configuration includes a valid SSL certificate, a DNS redirect from www to * and the following binding in IIS:

[image]

What could be the problem? Is it something related to DNS configuration or IIS?

Comment: Use the IIS URL Rewriting Extension. Don't abuse IIS Site bindings for that: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: @Dai I always recommend creating separate virtual hosts (bindings) if possible rather than using rewrite rules.  Rewrite rules are a hack that you have to use if you have shared hosting.

Comment: Your site bindings show cases for 1, 3, and 4.   How is #2 working?

Comment: It works since we have a DNS redirect from www to *

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I respectfully, but _vehemently_, disagree with your opinion. I’d post a treatise of technical arguments supporting my position but it’s 2am and I’m druuuuuuuunk right now.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "DNS redirect".  Redirects are handled by the HTTP protocol.  You have to have a web server running to be able to redirect.

Comment: @samwu Thanks for your reply but how could I do? Should I create a second virtual machine to install the website on it?

Comment: @samwu I wonder why the comment said "The problem should be you have multiple Host Names in one IP address". That's not a problem at all in IIS 8 and above, and a single IP address can host tons of HTTP/HTTPS bindings.

Comment: So what is the output of `nslookup example.com` and `nslookup www.example.com` at command prompt? Does the output show both domains point to the IP address of this server? If not, what's the device owning that IP address? A network gateway or a proxy? I suggest you ask your network administrators to assist in this situation, as the bindings you showed can only lead the conclusion made by @StephenOstermiller